# ¿Cómo obtener los elementos de un arreglo dado el múltiplo de un número en JS?

Tags: javascript

De ante mano, muchas gracias por su ayuda, quiero obtener los múltiplos de un arreglo, tomando como valor un número x.
Por ejemplo, tengo el siguiente array de fechas:

```
const showdates = [
  '2022/12/05',
  '2022/12/06',
  '2022/12/07',
  '2022/12/08',
  '2022/12/09',
  '2022/12/10',
  '2022/12/11',
  '2022/12/12',
  '2022/12/13',
  '2022/12/14',
];
```

El número x para este ejemplo es el número "3", es decir que de mi arreglo showDates necesito obtener los elementos que sean múltiplos de este número, es decir, el siguiente resultado:

```
[ '2022/12/07', '2022/12/10', '2022/12/13' ]
```

Ya que los múltiplos de **"3"** es 3,6,9, etc.
Realicé la siguiente solución, sin embargo, no siento que sea la mejor y por eso la razón de mi pregunta:
Mi solución:

```js
const showdates = [
  '2022/12/05',
  '2022/12/06',
  '2022/12/07',
  '2022/12/08',
  '2022/12/09',
  '2022/12/10',
  '2022/12/11',
  '2022/12/12',
  '2022/12/13',
  '2022/12/14',
];
const config = 3;
const multiplos = [];
for (let i = 1; i < showdates.length; i += 1) {
  if (i % config === 0) {
    multiplos.push(showdates[i - 1])
  }
}
console.log(multiplos)
```

Agradecería mucho cualquier otra solución, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar el resto, que obtenes con %

```js
const showdates = [
  '2022/12/05',
  '2022/12/06',
  '2022/12/07',
  '2022/12/08',
  '2022/12/09',
  '2022/12/10',
  '2022/12/11',
  '2022/12/12',
  '2022/12/13',
  '2022/12/14',
];

function esMultiplo(valor, multiplo){ // funcion que devuelve true si sus parametros son multiplos.
  resto = valor % multiplo;
  if(resto==0)  return true;
  else  return false;
}

let result = [];

showdates.forEach((element, index) => { // para cada fecha
  if(esMultiplo(index + 1, 3)) result.push(element); // si el indice es multiplo pusheo el elemento correspondiente a dicho indice
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts2.js" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

El index tiene -1 porque vos queres empezar teniendo un índice que comienza con 1 y no con 0, como tenes en la pregunta.